# How to make a simple getter via AIF in AX 2012?

Tags: web-services, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, aif

I have a simple getter Class in AX and would like to use it via an AIF webservice from an external program. The Class looks like this:

```
static Email getEMail(HcmWorkerRecId _hcmWorkerRecId)
{
    ;
    email = HcmWorker::find(_hcmWorkerRecId).Email();
    return email;
}
```

What do I need to get an AIF Webservice out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to add SysEntryPointAttribute Metadata attribute and set the method to public:

```
[SysEntryPointAttribute]
public Email getEMailByItemValueId(HcmWorkerRecId _hcmWorkerRecId)
{
    ;
    email = HcmWorker::find(_hcmWorkerRecId).Email();
    return email;
}
```

Then I added an service and an service group and deployed it.

A good help was this blogpost:
http://dynamics-ax.blogspot.de/2011/08/microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012-dive-into_10.html